# csv file is not printing in django webpage

Tags: python, django

I am new to django.I want upload the csv file,process the data and render the results it on UI.For that I have created the following code.
The problem is csv file is not uploading. If I'm uploaded other file format it not showing any error message.
Also I want to print csv data the results on UI.
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.conf import settings

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.contrib import messages

import csv

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import logging

def upload_csv(request):

    data = {}
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, "myapp/upload_csv.html", data)
    # if not GET, then proceed
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            c=messages.error(request,'File is not CSV type')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:upload_csv",{"c":c}))
        #if file is too large, return
        if csv_file.multiple_chunks():

            messages.error(request,"Uploaded file is too big (%.2f MB)." % (csv_file.size/(1000*1000),))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:upload_csv"))

        file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")

        lines = file_data.split("\n")
        #loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
        for line in lines:
            fields = line.split(",")
            data_dict = {}
            data_dict["GSTIN/UIN"] = fields[0]
            data_dict["start_date_time"] = fields[1]
            data_dict["end_date_time"] = fields[2]
            data_dict["notes"] = fields[3]
            try:
                form = EventsForm(data_dict)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                else:
                    logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(form.errors.as_json())
            except Exception as e:
                logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(repr(e))
                pass

    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))
        messages.error(request,"Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))

    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:index",data_dict))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("myapp/upload_csv.html")
```

**html**

```html
<html> <form action="{% url "myapp:upload_csv" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">File: </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" required="True" class="form-control">

    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
         <button class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Upload </button>
    </div>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>

{% if c %}
<p> {{c}} <p>
  {% endif %}
</form> </html>
```

Also help me to print the csv data on UI

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the file to the template at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be passing data to you html file via the context.  You'll need to amend your code something like.

```
    rows = []
    lines = file_data.split("\n")
    #loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split(",")
        data_dict = {}
        data_dict["GSTIN/UIN"] = fields[0]
        data_dict["start_date_time"] = fields[1]
        data_dict["end_date_time"] = fields[2]
        data_dict["notes"] = fields[3]
        try:
            form = EventsForm(data_dict)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(form.errors.as_json())
        except Exception as e:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(repr(e))
            pass
        rows.append(line)

except Exception as e:
    logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))
    messages.error(request,"Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))

variables = {}
variables['lines'] = rows

#return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:index",data_dict))
return render(request,"myapp/upload_csv.html", variables)
```

Then in the html file

```
<table>
{% for line in lines %}
    <tr><td>{{ line.0 }}</td><td>{{ line.1 }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

There might be a couple of typos in here but it should set you in right direction